# Glue Job fails to write file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am back filling some data via glue jobs.  The job itself is reading in a TSV from s3, transforming the data slightly, and writing it in Parquet to S3.  Since I already have the data, I am trying to launch multiple jobs at once to reduce the amount of time needed to process it all.  When I launch multiple jobs at the same time, I run into an issue sometimes where one of the files will fail to output the resultant Parquet files in S3.  The job itself completes successfully without throwing an error  When I rerun the job as a non-parallel task, the file it output correctly.  Is there some issue, either with glue(or the underlying spark) or S3 that would cause my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same Glue job running in parallel may produce files with the same names and therefore some of them can be overwritten. As I remember correctly, transformation-context is used as part of the name. I assume you don't have bookmarking enabled so it should be safe for you to generate transformation-context value dynamically to ensure it's unique for each job.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me nuts